# How to use objects returned by a function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There's a pokki function `pokki.getWorkAreaSize()` which returns an object containing height and width of the working area.

How do I use those values as CSS property ?

For example `<object style="width:0px;height:0px;"></object>` I want the width and height of that object to be the one returned by the function.

Comment: Post an example of what `pokki.getWorkAreaSize()` returns.

Comment: If I do a `console.log(pokki.getWorkAreaSize());` I get an Object containing `height: 870` and `width: 1440`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an identity for the element. then you could do like,

```
<object id="obj1" style="width:0px;height:0px;"></object>

var size = pokki.getWorkAreaSize();
var obj1 = document.getElementById("obj1");
obj1.style.width = size.width + "px";
obj1.style.height = size.height + "px";
```

hope this helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks alot!